# Trying to swap values of the first and the last array elements

Tags: java, arrays, methods

void swapEven(int[] array)

In a given array of integers nums swap values of the first and the last array elements, the second and the penultimate, and so on, if both of these exchanged values are even.

Note that input array may be empty.

Examples
Code Sample:

...
int[] array = new int[]{ 10, 5, 3, 4 };
....
Output:

[4, 5, 3, 10]

my code:

```
public class FirstProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = new int[]{100, 2, 3, 45, 33, 8, 4, 54};
        swapEven(myArray);

    }

    public static void swapEven(int[] array) {
        // TODO: Implement this method.
        int temp, firstNumIndex, secondNumIndex, counter = 1;
        if (array != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
                    firstNumIndex = i;
                    if (array[array.length - counter] % 2 == 0) {
                        secondNumIndex = array.length - counter;
                        temp = array[firstNumIndex];
                        array[firstNumIndex] = array[secondNumIndex];
                        array[secondNumIndex] = temp;
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            }
        } else {
            array = new int[]{};
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }

    }
}
```

Trying to figure out why it is giving me the same array as input. It doesn't swap array.
Am I returning a wrong array, should I create a second array to add values and then retun?

Comment: You iterate over the entire array. Which means that if you swapped an element in the first half, you will swap it back again when you reach it again in the second half.

Comment: Also this is the exact use-case for a debugger, which is one of the most important tools in a programmer's skillset

Answer (score 3):

You almost have it!!  Once you swap the even values you are reswapping them.  So just iterate across half the array.  You can see this if you place

```
System.out.printf("Swapping %d with %d%n",
       array[firstNumIndex], array[secondNumIndex]);
```

right before you start swapping.  To fix it change your `for loop` to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length/2; i++) {
```

Here is an an alternative form.

You only need a single regular for loop as you are doing.

- iterate `left` just halfway thru the array.
- assign `right` to the current right most position base on the value of `left`.
- check to ensure both are even values.
- if so swap them.

Note that this works for both even and odd length arrays.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
swapEven(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

prints

```
[1, 10, 3, 8, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9, 2, 11]
```

The method

```
public static void swapEven(int[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        System.out.println("Array is null");
        return;
    }
    for (int left = 0; left < array.length / 2; left++) {
        int right = array.length - left - 1;
        if (array[left] % 2 == 0 && array[right] % 2 == 0) {
            int temp = array[left];
            array[left] = array[right];
            array[right] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note.**  If you ever need to just reverse an array, you can do this by just omitting the check for even values.

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over the entire length of the array, all the even elements will be swapped twice (which returns them all to their original positions).

You should instead loop over half of the array. You could use two indexes to track the position from the front and the back, stopping when they pass each other.

```java
for (int i = 0, j = array.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[j] % 2 == 0) {
        int t = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... In a given array of integers nums swap values of the first and the last array elements, the second and the penultimate, and so on, if both of these exchanged values are even. ..."*

Here is an example.

You'll only need to traverse half of the *array*.
Access the opposing indices, with *(n − 1) − i*.

```java
void swap(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0, t, n = a.length, m = n / 2; i < m; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0 && a[n - 1 - i] % 2 == 0) {
            t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[n - 1 - i];
            a[n - 1 - i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternately, use a *stream*.

```java
void swap(int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    IntStream.range(0, n / 2)
             .forEach(
                 x -> {
                     if (a[x] % 2 == 0 && a[n - 1 - x] % 2 == 0) {
                         int t = a[x];
                         a[x] = a[n - 1 - x];
                         a[n - 1 - x] = t;
                     }
                 });
}
```

And, if you're using a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)*, you can utilize the *[Collections#swap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,int,int))* method.

```java
void swap(List<Integer> l) {
    for (int i = 0, n = l.size(), m = n / 2; i < m; i++)
        if (l.get(i) % 2 == 0 && l.get(n - 1 - i) % 2 == 0)
            Collections.swap(l, i, n - 1 - i);
}
```

Output

```
[4, 5, 3, 10]
```

```
[54, 4, 3, 45, 33, 8, 2, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the way the array is initialized when it is empty. Instead of assigning a new array to the argument, you should handle the case where the input array is empty. You can also simplify the swap logic.You can do something like:

```js
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FirstProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = new int[]{100, 2, 3, 45, 33, 8, 4, 54};
        swapEven(myArray);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
    }

    public static void swapEven(int[] array) {
        if (array != null && array.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
                if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[array.length - 1 - i] % 2 == 0) {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
                    array[array.length - 1 - i] = temp;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input array is empty or null.");
        }
    }
}
```