# issue in reversing a string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, reverse

cant reverse my string using char[] array
if my input is geeks and output shpuld be skeeg
if i reverse using charAt function it reverse the string correctly if i use the reverse[i]=reverse[j] i cant reverse it properly where (j=length of reverse)  for clear view please view my code .
the above code gives me output as wrong for example if my input is geeks it gives output as skeks
if i change the line reverseword[j] = reverseword[i]; to reverseword[j] = test.charAt(i); it gives coorect output.
since reversedword also contains the same word but it gives issue while reversing a string but when using test.chatAt it works?
whats the issue in reversing a string using reverseword[j] = reverseword[i];?

```
class reverse {

    public static String sample(String str) {
        String test = str;
        char[] reverseword;

        reverseword = test.toCharArray();

        int j = 0;
        
        for (int i = reverseword.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverseword[j] = reverseword[i];
            j++;
        }

        String finalresult = new String(reverseword);
        return finalresult;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting the data. You need to work in from both ends, meet in the middle, and use a temporary char variable to prevent overwriting the data as you go. The reason it works with `charAt` is because strings are immutable so you can't destroy the data while you're reversing it.

Comment: And that's exactly what you should use: `reverseword[j] = str.charAt(i);
` and begin by creating an empty array And of course you can do `return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();`

Comment: Check out the example at the end of [reverse an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77466881/1552534).  You can do the same thing with an array of characters and the return a new String of those characters.  Note that you only need to iterate half way from each end towards the middle.

Comment: This might not apply to your exercise, but note that reversing a Java string using a character array will break if the string contains one or more  UTF-16 surrogate pairs. It's probably better to work with integer code points, e.g. String#codePoints().

Comment: Try the following, _String s = ""; for (char c : "geeks".toCharArray()) s = c + s;_.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are trying to read and write data in the same array at the same time, which is causing data loss. When you start reading data from the end of the array and write it to the beginning of the array, you are actually overwriting the original data.To fix this, you need to create a new array to store the reversed characters, so you're not overwriting the original characters.

However, when you use the `charAt`, you are reading the original string, which has not been modified the entire process. So you can correctly take the character from the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two algorithmic problems:

- `reverseword[j] = reverseword[i];` overwrites the character at index `j` and leaves the char at `i` as is. You can use a temporary variable to swap these two values;
- by running the for loop from `reverseword.length - 1` to `0`, even if you use a temporary variable, you are going to swap them correctly, but you are going to do it twice and end up with the initial array.

Below is a code that fixes it (and adds another way of reversing a string):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for(String arg: args) {
            System.out.println(arg + " <-> " + reverse(arg));
            System.out.println(arg + " <-> " + reverse2(arg));
        }
    }

    static String reverse(String value) {
        char [] characters = value.toCharArray();

        int len = characters.length;
        for (int i = 0; i <= len/2 - 1; i++) {
            char tmp = characters[i];
            characters[i] = characters[len-i-1];
            characters[len-i-1] = tmp;
        }
        return new String(characters);
    }

    static String reverse2(String value) {
        StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(value);
        return reverse.reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use below code, which makes it 2 times faster, and works with no issue.

```
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i< arr.length/2; i++){
    char temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length-1-i];
    arr[arr.length-1-i] = temp;
}

return new String(arr);
```